# Objective-C IOS - Keep view alive when even with transitions

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I have a iphone app that is usign CCLocation. I get my view and track the distance that I need just fine.

When I switch from one view to an other (see as one screen to another) within my app, I get a dealloc and loose the GPS tracking.

What is bizzare, is that I can keep it to work if the user stays on the view and switched app (using multi-tasking) but I can't seem to get it to multi-task within my own app!?

Any idea on how to prevent a view to release itself?

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the MVC paradigm, you should probably put your GPS/Location tracking code in a Model or Controller object that is retained, not inside a View object that can get released.

Comment: Thanks, I read further about the Multi-tasking on the iphone and realized I had it wrong. I implemented a proper MVC and it is working fine. Thanks.